# How to execute/override a JavaScript function declared in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, overriding, anonymous-function

How can I execute a function that is defined in an anonymous function ?

For example, I've this method "openProfile" declared in anonymous function. I would like to override it / call it

```js
function(e, t, n) {
  "use strict";
  (function(e) {
      function a(e) {
        return e && e.__esModule ? e : {
          default: e
        }
      }
      Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
      });
      var i = n(1)
        , r = a(i)
        , o = n(3)
        , s = a(o)
        , u = n(4)
        , d = a(u)
        , l = n(18)
        , c = a(l)
        , f = n(214)
        , p = a(f);
      t.default = {
        init: function() {
          var t = this;
          p.default.langLoad("ui"),
            (0,
              r.default)(e.document).on("click", "[data-profile]", function(e) {
              return t.openProfile((0,
                r.default)(e.currentTarget).data("profile"))
            })
        },
        openProfile: function(t) {
          var n = this;
          // etc
        }
      }
    }
  ).call(t, n(2))
}
```

Comment: nope............

Comment: @epascarello nop it's not possible ?

Comment: `function(e, t, n) {..}` is invalid syntax, is that something like `var a = function(e, t, n) {..}` ?

Comment: If you CALL that outer function, passing an object (say `xxx`) as the second parameter, the function you want will be added as `xxx.default.openProfile`.  That assumes the outer function doesn't have any undesirable side effects.

Comment: Please show the complete code that uses the outer function

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Bergi here is the complete code, but it's huge as it's a compiled code https://jsfiddle.net/uovacz3n/ .
Titus yet that's how it's declared, see the jsfiddle link. Tim Roberts ok but the fact is I don't know what's the object name.

Comment: You can also create am element that matches the `[data-profile]` selector can call `click` on it. That will call the `openProfile` function but probably not with the argument that you want.